# Advanced Logging Function

Tags: console, logging, powershell

Way more blood, sweat, and tears have went into this then I would care to admit, but this has been a function I have been using in some shape or form for quite a while and it has taught me alot.

It does exactly what I want it to do ATM but happy to hear any suggestions on what could make it run more efficent. I am looking at making a buffer queue for the streamwriter to improve write performance but for for scripts is doesn't really seem necessary, more just of a fun little addition to add.

Will most likely add the ability to write to event log next, but again there is no real need for it at this time.

```
function Write-Tee {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [Switch]$Close,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
        [String]$Message,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [ValidateSet('Fatal','Error','Warning','Info','Trace')]
        [String]$Severity,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [Switch]$WriteToHost=$True,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [Switch]$WriteToLog=$True,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [Switch]$FirstRun=$False
    )
    Begin {
        $Logtime = [datetime]::Now
        #Function specific settings used for customization.
        [Int]$LoggingLevel  = 3
        [Bool]$WriteLog     = $True
        [Bool]$WriteConsole = $True
        [Int]$LogBuffer     = 25
        [String]$LogPath    = ''
        [String]$LogName    = ''

        Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

        #Make sure previous streamwriters are closed out prior to starting script.
        If((test-path variable:\WriteTee) -and $FirstRun) {
            Write-Tee -Close
        } ElseIf (!(test-path variable:\WriteTee) -OR $FirstRun) {
            New-Variable -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force -Name WriteTee -Value @{} -Scope Script
            $Script:WriteTee.RunOnce = $True
        }

        If ($WriteTee.RunOnce) {
            #Set important functional variables
            $Script:WriteTee.RunOnce = $False
            $Script:WriteTee.Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            $Script:WriteTee.SID = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
            If ($Host.name -eq "Windows PowerShell ISE Host") {
                $Script:WriteTee.ForegroundColor = 'White'
                $Script:WriteTee.BackgroundColor = 'DarkMagenta'
            } Else {
                $Script:WriteTee.Host = (get-host).ui.rawui
                $Script:WriteTee.ForegroundColor = $Script:WriteTee.Host.ForegroundColor
                $Script:WriteTee.BackgroundColor = $Script:WriteTee.Host.BackgroundColor
            }

            #Dynamicly pull any script defined variables.
            If (Test-Path Variable:\Script) {
                If ($Script.ContainsKey("WriteTee")) {
                    ForEach ($Key in $Script.WriteTee.GetEnumerator()) {
                        $Script:WriteTee.$($Key.Name) = $Key.Value
                    }
                }
            }

            #Dynamicly Convert REQUIRED funciton config to variables if not already defined.
            ForEach ($Var in ("LogLevel","WriteLog","WriteConsole","LogBuffer","LogPath","LogName")) {
                If (!$WriteTee.ContainsKey("$Var")) {
                    $WriteTee.Temp = Get-Variable -Name $Var -ValueOnly -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                    IF ($WriteTee.Temp -OR $Var -IN ("LogPath","LogName")) {
                        $WriteTee.$Var = $WriteTee.Temp
                    } Else {
                        Throw "$Var is not defined in either `$Script nor in the function config."
                    }
                }
                $WriteTee.Remove('Temp')
            }

            #Ensures there is a valid log level set.
            If ($WriteTee.LogLevel -LT 1 -OR $WriteTee.LogLevel -GT 5) {
                Write-Error "`$LogLevel does not contain a value between 1 and 5"
            }


            If ($WriteTee.WriteLog) {


                    $WriteTee.LogPaths = $WriteTee.LogPath,
                         $(split-path -parent $Script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition),
                         $Env:UserProfile
                    #Verify that the logname is in a usable format.
                    Try {
                        $WriteTee.LogName = [System.IO.FileInfo]$WriteTee.LogName
                    } Catch {
                        $WriteTee.LogName = "$(([System.IO.FileInfo](split-path -leaf $Script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)).BaseName).log"
                    }

                    #Find the first usable log file.
                    Foreach ($Path in $WriteTee.LogPaths) {
                        If ($WriteTee.ContainsKey('LogFile')) {
                            Continue
                        } Else {
                            Try {
                                $Path = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$Path
                            } Catch {
                                #If you can't convert it, script can't use it.
                                Continue
                            }
                        }

                        #Ensure the directory exists and if not, create it.
                        If (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists($Path)) {
                            Try {
                                #Create the directory because .Net will error out if you try to create a file in a directory that doesn't exist yet.
                                New-Item -Path $Path.Parent.FullName -Name $Path.BaseName -ItemType 'Directory' -ErrorAction Stop -Force |Out-Null
                            } Catch {
                                Continue
                            }
                        }#End-If

                        #Check to see if there are any existing logs
                        $WriteTee.ExistingLogs = @(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Path.FullName -Filter "$(([System.IO.FileInfo]$WriteTee.LogName).BaseName)*$(([System.IO.FileInfo]$WriteTee.LogName).Extension)" |Sort-Object)
                        If ($WriteTee.ExistingLogs.Count -GT 0) {
                            ForEach ($ExistingLog in $WriteTee.ExistingLogs) {
                                Try {
                                    [io.file]::OpenWrite($ExistingLog.FullName).close() |Out-Null
                                    $Script:WriteTee.LogFile = $ExistingLog.FullName
                                    break
                                } Catch {
                                    $WriteTee.LastLogName = $ExistingLog
                                    Continue
                                }
                            }
                            If ($Script:WriteTee.ContainsKey('LogFile')) {Break}
                        }#End-If

                        #If no previous logs can be added to create a new one.
                        switch ($WriteTee.ExistingLogs.Count) {
                            {$PSItem -EQ 0} {
                                $WriteTee.TestLogFile = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath $WriteTee.LogName
                            }
                            {$PSItem -EQ 1} {
                                $WriteTee.TestLogFile = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath ($WriteTee.LastLogName.basename + '[0]' + $WriteTee.LastLogName.Extension)
                            }

                            {$PSItem -GE 2} {
                                $WriteTee.TestLogFile = $WriteTee.LastLogName.FullName.Split('[]')
                                $WriteTee.TestLogFile = ($WriteTee.TestLogFile[0] + '[' + (([int]$WriteTee.TestLogFile[1]) + 1) + ']' + $WriteTee.TestLogFile[2])
                            }
                            Default {
                                Write-Host "If you are looking for an explanation of how you got here, I can tell you I don't have one. But what I do have are a very particular lack of answers that I have aquired over a very long career that make these problems a nightmare for people like me."
                                Continue
                                }
                        }#End-Switch

                        #Last but not least, try to create the file and hope it is successful.
                        Try {
                            [IO.File]::Create($WriteTee.TestLogFile, 1, 'None').close() |Out-Null
                            $Script:WriteTee.LogFile = $WriteTee.TestLogFile
                            $WriteTee.NewFile = $True
                            Break
                        } Catch {
                            Continue
                        }
                    }#End-ForEach

                #Rev up the StreamWriter
                $Script:WriteTee.StreamWriter = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList "$($Script:WriteTee.LogFile)",$True,$([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode)
                If ($WriteTee.ContainsKey('NewFile')) {
                    $Script:WriteTee.StreamWriter.WriteLine("Computer Name`tSecurity Principal`tDate`tTime`tScript Phase`tLine Number`tMessage")
                }
            }#EndIf
        }#EndIf

        #Convert easily readable severity to INT to determine log output level.


        Switch ($Severity) {
            'Trace'   {$WriteTee.ErrorLevel = '5'; $WriteTee.FGColor=$Script:WriteTee.ForegroundColor; $WriteTee.BGColor = $Script:WriteTee.BackgroundColor;}
            'Info'    {$WriteTee.ErrorLevel = '4'; $WriteTee.FGColor=$Script:WriteTee.ForegroundColor; $WriteTee.BGColor = $Script:WriteTee.BackgroundColor;}
            'Warning' {$WriteTee.ErrorLevel = '3'; $WriteTee.FGColor='Yellow'; $WriteTee.BGColor = 'Black';}
            'Error'   {$WriteTee.ErrorLevel = '2'; $WriteTee.FGColor='Red'; $WriteTee.BGColor = 'Black';}
            'Fatal'   {$WriteTee.ErrorLevel = '1'; $WriteTee.FGColor='Red'; $WriteTee.BGColor = 'Black';}
            Default   {$WriteTee.ErrorLevel = '0'}
        }#EndSwitch

        #If the script doesn't meet the minimum log level, disable output running.
        If ($WriteTee.ErrorLevel -GT $WriteTee.LogLevel) { 
            $WriteTee.Skip = $True
        } ElseIF($WriteTee.ErrorLevel -EQ 0 -AND !$Message) {
            $WriteTee.Skip = $True
            #Write-Error -message "Severity level must be defined"
        } Else {
            #Convert Date Time to more usable format.
            $WriteTee.Skip = $False
            $WriteTee.Time = $Logtime.ToString('HH:mm:ss,fff')
            $WriteTee.Date = $Logtime.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
            $WriteTee.Line = $MyInvocation.ScriptLineNumber
        }

    }#End-Begin

    Process {
        If ($WriteTee.Skip -EQ $False) {
            IF ($WriteTee.WriteConsole) {
                $WriteTee.OutConsole = "$($WriteTee.Date) $($WriteTee.Time) - $($Script.Phase) - $($WriteTee.Line) - $Message"
                Write-Host -Object $WriteTee.OutConsole -ForegroundColor $WriteTee.FGColor -BackgroundColor $WriteTee.BGColor
            }
            ## Write output to log file.
            IF ($WriteTee.WriteLog) {
                $WriteTee.OutLog = "$($Script:WriteTee.Computer)`t$($Script:WriteTee.SID)`t$($WriteTee.Date)`t$($WriteTee.Time)`t$($Script.Phase)`t$($WriteTee.Line)`t$Message"
                $Script:WriteTee.StreamWriter.WriteLine($WriteTee.OutLog)
            }
        }
    }#End-Process
    End {
        If ($Close -AND $Script:WriteTee) {
            $Script:WriteTee.StreamWriter.Flush()
            $Script:WriteTee.StreamWriter.Close()
            Remove-Variable -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force -Name WriteTee -Scope Script
        }#End-If
    }#End-End

}
clear
$Script = @{}
$Script.WriteTee = @{}
$Script.WriteTee.LogLevel = 5
$Script.Phase = "Debug"

Write-Tee -Message "This is AWESOME!" -Severity Info
Write-Tee -Close
```

Comment: try to see at [Logging module](https://github.com/EsOsO/Logging). it use a separate thread for logging process.